# Heteroscedasticity Test for Random Effects Model

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I'm running a random effects model using the `plm` package and now I need to test for the presence of heteroscedasticity, but I'm not sure how to process it in the mentioned package.

My model:

```
random <- plm(Y ~ X, data=panel_data, model= "random", effect = "twoways")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can test for heteroskedasticity and cross-sectional dependence using the  `plm::pcdtest()` function, as documented on page 50 of the [plm package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf). A comprehensive walkthrough illustrating how to interpret the results from `plm` random and fixed effect models is [Getting Started with Fixed and Random Effects Models in R](https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101R.pdf) and is available on the Princeton University's Data and Statistical Services website.

Using an example from the `plm` vignette:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
g <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, index = c("firm", "year"))
pcdtest(g)
```

...and the results:

```
> pcdtest(g)

    Pesaran CD test for cross-sectional dependence in panels

data:  inv ~ value + capital
z = 4.6612, p-value = 3.144e-06
alternative hypothesis: cross-sectional dependence
```